# C++ line-editing micro-library

Tags: c++, library, user-interface, unix

Working on a project, I've taken to adapting the [linenoise line editing library](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise) for my own use, among other things, rewriting it using C++. The idea is to separate my changes and updates into a new library, and publish it on GitHub, as one does. But before I release my changes into the wild, I'd like to ensure that it is, you know, good.

What I would like is general notes on correctness and practices.

(History not being implemented is a known issue.)

#### linenoise.h

```cpp
/* linenoise.h -- guerrilla line editing library against the idea that a
 * line editing lib needs to be 20,000 lines of C code.
 *
 * See linenoise.cpp for more information.
 *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014-2014, Williham Totland <williham dot totland at gmail dot com>
 * Copyright (c) 2010-2014, Salvatore Sanfilippo <antirez at gmail dot com>
 * Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Pieter Noordhuis <pcnoordhuis at gmail dot com>
 *
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * BSD 2-term, abbreviated for clarity.
 */

#import <unistd.h>

#import <unordered_set>
#import <string>
#import <deque>

namespace linenoise {

  typedef struct termios termiosSettings;

  class terminal {
    friend class editor;

    std::unordered_set<std::string> unsupportedTerminals;
    int inputFileDescriptor, outputFileDescriptor;

    termiosSettings *original, *rawMode;
    bool initializeRawMode ();

    size_t cursorPosition ();
    size_t columns ();

    void clearScreen ();
  public:
    terminal(const std::unordered_set<std::string> &uT, int ifd, int ofd) : unsupportedTerminals(uT), inputFileDescriptor(ifd), outputFileDescriptor(ofd) {
      initializeRawMode();
    }

    bool supported () const;

    bool enableRawMode (int);
    void disableRawMode (int);

    static void beep ();
  };

  class editor {
    enum class keyAction;

    class cursor {
      friend class editor;

      const editor &editor;

      size_t position;
    public:
      cursor(const class editor &e) : editor(e), position(0) { }

      void home (), left (), right (), end ();
    };

    cursor cursor;

    class history : public std::deque<const std::string> {
      friend class editor;

      void add (const std::string &);

      void save (const std::string &), load (const std::string &);
    };

    history history;
    ssize_t hCursor;

    std::string lineBuffer;
    std::string killBuffer = "";

    terminal term;
    bool hasSupportedTerminal;

    bool edit (int, int);

    void insert (char c);

    void kill (bool line), yank (), swap ();
    void deleteBack (), deleteForward (), deleteWord ();

    void historyPrev (), historyNext ();

    size_t completeLine ();
  public:
    std::string prompt;
    bool done = false;

    editor() : cursor(*this), term({"dumb", "cons25", "emacs", ""}, STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO), hasSupportedTerminal(term.supported()) { }

    std::string getline ();

    void refresh ();
  };

}
```

#### linenoise.cpp

```cpp
/* linenoise.cpp -- guerrilla line editing library against the idea that a
 * line editing lib needs to be 20,000 lines of C code.
 *
 * You can find the latest source code at:
 *
 *   http://github.com/antirez/linenoise
 *
 * Does a number of crazy assumptions that happen to be true in 99.9999% of
 * the 2010 UNIX computers around.
 *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014-2014, Williham Totland <williham dot totland at gmail dot com>
 * Copyright (c) 2010-2014, Salvatore Sanfilippo <antirez at gmail dot com>
 * Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Pieter Noordhuis <pcnoordhuis at gmail dot com>
 *
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * BSD 2-term, abbreviated for clarity
 *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * References:
 * - http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html
 * - http://www.3waylabs.com/nw/WWW/products/wizcon/vt220.html
 *
 * Todo list:
 * - Filter bogus Ctrl+<char> combinations.
 * - Win32 support
 *
 * Bloat:
 * - History search like Ctrl+r in readline?
 *
 * List of escape sequences used by this program, we do everything just
 * with three sequences. In order to be so cheap we may have some
 * flickering effect with some slow terminal, but the lesser sequences
 * the more compatible.
 *
 * EL (Erase Line)
 *    Sequence: ESC [ n K
 *    Effect: if n is 0 or missing, clear from cursor to end of line
 *    Effect: if n is 1, clear from beginning of line to cursor
 *    Effect: if n is 2, clear entire line
 *
 * CUF (CUrsor Forward)
 *    Sequence: ESC [ n C
 *    Effect: moves cursor forward n chars
 *
 * CUB (CUrsor Backward)
 *    Sequence: ESC [ n D
 *    Effect: moves cursor backward n chars
 *
 * The following is used to get the terminal width if getting
 * the width with the TIOCGWINSZ ioctl fails
 *
 * DSR (Device Status Report)
 *    Sequence: ESC [ 6 n
 *    Effect: reports the current cusor position as ESC [ n ; m R
 *            where n is the row and m is the column
 *
 * When multi line mode is enabled, we also use an additional escape
 * sequence. However multi line editing is disabled by default.
 *
 * CUU (Cursor Up)
 *    Sequence: ESC [ n A
 *    Effect: moves cursor up of n chars.
 *
 * CUD (Cursor Down)
 *    Sequence: ESC [ n B
 *    Effect: moves cursor down of n chars.
 *
 * When linenoiseClearScreen() is called, two additional escape sequences
 * are used in order to clear the screen and position the cursor at home
 * position.
 *
 * CUP (Cursor position)
 *    Sequence: ESC [ H
 *    Effect: moves the cursor to upper left corner
 *
 * ED (Erase display)
 *    Sequence: ESC [ 2 J
 *    Effect: clear the whole screen
 *
 */

#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#import <string>
#import <sstream>
#import <unordered_set>
#import <iostream>

#import "linenoise.h"

namespace linenoise {

  enum class editor::keyAction {
    KEY_NULL  =   0,
    CTRL_A    =   1,
    CTRL_B    =   2,
    CTRL_C    =   3,
    CTRL_D    =   4,
    CTRL_E    =   5,
    CTRL_F    =   6,
    CTRL_H    =   8,
    CTRL_I    =   9,
    TAB       =   9,
    CTRL_K    =  11,
    CTRL_L    =  12,
    ENTER     =  13,
    CTRL_N    =  14,
    CTRL_P    =  16,
    CTRL_T    =  20,
    CTRL_U    =  21,
    CTRL_W    =  23,
    CTRL_Y    =  25,
    ESC       =  27,
    BACKSPACE = 127,
  };

#pragma mark linenoise::terminal

  bool terminal::supported () const {
    const char *cterm(getenv("TERM"));
    const std::string term(cterm?cterm:"");

    return (unsupportedTerminals.find(term) == unsupportedTerminals.end());
  }

  bool terminal::initializeRawMode () {
    if (!isatty(inputFileDescriptor))
      return false;

    original = (termiosSettings *)malloc(sizeof(termiosSettings));
    tcgetattr(inputFileDescriptor, original);
    rawMode  = (termiosSettings *)malloc(sizeof(termiosSettings));
    rawMode  = (termiosSettings *)memcpy(rawMode, original, sizeof(termiosSettings));

    termiosSettings &raw = *rawMode;
    raw.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON);
    raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
    raw.c_cflag |= (CS8);
    raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
    raw.c_cc[VMIN] = 1; raw.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    return true;
  }

  bool terminal::enableRawMode (int fd) {
    if (tcsetattr(fd,TCSAFLUSH,rawMode) >= 0)
      return true;

    errno = ENOTTY;
    return false;
  }

  void terminal::disableRawMode (int fd) {
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSAFLUSH,original);
  }

  /* Use the ESC [6n escape sequence to query the horizontal cursor position
   * and return it. On error -1 is returned, on success the position of the
   * cursor. */
  size_t terminal::cursorPosition () {
    char buf[32];
    int cols, rows;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    if (write(outputFileDescriptor, "\x1b[6n", 4) != 4) return -1;

    /* Read the response: ESC [ rows ; cols R */
    while (i < sizeof(buf)-1) {
      if (read(inputFileDescriptor, buf + i, 1) != 1) break;
      if (buf[i] == 'R') break;
      i++;
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';

    if (sscanf(buf,"\x1b[%d;%d", &rows, &cols) != 2) return -1;
    return cols;
  }

  size_t terminal::columns () {
    struct winsize ws;

    if (ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws) == -1 || ws.ws_col == 0) {
      size_t start, cols;

      start = cursorPosition();

      write(outputFileDescriptor, "\x1b[999C", 6);
      cols = cursorPosition();

      if (cols > start) {
        char seq[32];
        snprintf(seq,32,"\x1b[%luD", cols - start);
        write(outputFileDescriptor, seq, strlen(seq));
      }

      return cols;
    } else {
      return ws.ws_col;
    }

    return 80;
  }

  void terminal::clearScreen () {
    write(outputFileDescriptor,"\x1b[H\x1b[2J",7);
  }

  void terminal::beep () {
    fprintf(stderr, "\x7");
    fflush(stderr);
  }

#pragma mark linenoise::editor::cursor

  void editor::cursor::home () {
    position = 0;
  }

  void editor::cursor::left () {
    size_t max = editor.lineBuffer.size();

    if (position > max)
      position = max;

    if (position > 0)
      --position;
  }

  void editor::cursor::right () {
    size_t max = editor.lineBuffer.size();

    if (position < max)
      ++position;
    else
      position = max;
  }

  void editor::cursor::end () {
    position = editor.lineBuffer.size();
  }

#pragma mark linenoise::editor::history

  void editor::history::add (const std::string &) {

  }

  void editor::history::load (const std::string &) {

  }

  void editor::history::save (const std::string &) {

  }

#pragma mark linenoise::editor

  void editor::refresh () {
    int fd = term.outputFileDescriptor;

    size_t plen = prompt.size();
    size_t pos(cursor.position);

    size_t availableColumns(term.columns() - prompt.size());
    size_t offset(0);

    while ((pos - offset) >= availableColumns) {
      offset++;
    }

    std::stringstream ab;

    ab << "\r" << prompt << lineBuffer.substr(offset, availableColumns) << "\x1b[0K" << "\r\x1b[" << pos + plen - offset << "C";

    const char *abuf = ab.str().c_str();
    write(fd, abuf, strlen(abuf));
  }

  void editor::insert (char c) {
    lineBuffer.insert(cursor.position++, 1, c);
  }

  void editor::kill (bool line) {
    if (line)
      cursor.position = 0;

    if (cursor.position == lineBuffer.length())
      return;

    killBuffer = lineBuffer.substr(cursor.position);
    lineBuffer.erase(cursor.position);
  }

  void editor::yank () {
    lineBuffer.insert(cursor.position, killBuffer);
    cursor.position += killBuffer.length();
  }

  void editor::swap () {
    if (cursor.position != 0) {
      if (cursor.position == lineBuffer.length())
        --cursor.position;

      char c(lineBuffer[cursor.position - 1]);
      deleteBack();
      ++cursor.position;
      insert(c);
    }
  }

  void editor::deleteBack () {
    if (cursor.position > 0) {
      lineBuffer.erase(--cursor.position, 1);
    }
  }

  void editor::deleteForward () {
    lineBuffer.erase(cursor.position, 1);
  }

  void editor::deleteWord () {
    size_t old_pos(cursor.position);

    while (cursor.position > 0 && lineBuffer[cursor.position - 1] == ' ')
      --cursor.position;

    while (cursor.position > 0 && lineBuffer[cursor.position - 1] != ' ')
      --cursor.position;

    lineBuffer.erase(cursor.position, old_pos - cursor.position);
  }

  void editor::historyNext () {

  }

  void editor::historyPrev () {

  }

  bool editor::edit (int stdin_fd, int stdout_fd) {
    lineBuffer = "";
    cursor.position = 0;
    hCursor = -1;

    size_t len(0);

    std::cout << prompt << std::flush;

    while (1) {
      char c;
      ssize_t nread;
      char seq[3];
      len = lineBuffer.length();

      nread = read(term.inputFileDescriptor,&c,1);

      switch ((keyAction)c) {
        case keyAction::ENTER:
          history.add(lineBuffer);
          return true;
        case keyAction::BACKSPACE:
        case keyAction::CTRL_H:
          deleteBack();
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_C:
          return false;
        case keyAction::CTRL_D:
          if (len > 0) {
            deleteForward();
          } else {
            done = true;
            return false;
          }
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_T:
          swap();
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_B:
          cursor.left();
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_F:
          cursor.right();
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_P:
          historyPrev();
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_N:
          historyNext();
          break;
        case keyAction::ESC:
          /* Read the next two bytes representing the escape sequence.
           * Use two calls to handle slow terminals returning the two
           * chars at different times. */
          if (read(term.inputFileDescriptor,seq,1) == -1) break;
          if (read(term.inputFileDescriptor,seq+1,1) == -1) break;

          if (seq[0] == '[') {
            if (seq[1] >= '0' && seq[1] <= '9') {
              if (read(term.inputFileDescriptor,seq+2,1) == -1) break;
              if (seq[2] == '~') {
                switch(seq[1]) {
                  case '3':
                    deleteForward();
                    break;
                }
              }
            } else {
              switch(seq[1]) {
                case 'A':
                  historyPrev();
                  break;
                case 'B':
                  historyNext();
                  break;
                case 'C':
                  cursor.right();
                  break;
                case 'D':
                  cursor.left();
                  break;
                case 'H':
                  cursor.home();
                  break;
                case 'F':
                  cursor.end();
                  break;
              }
            }
          } else if (seq[0] == 'O') {
            switch(seq[1]) {
              case 'H':
                cursor.home();
                break;
              case 'F':
                cursor.end();
                break;
            }
          }
          break;
        default:
          insert(c);
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_U:
          kill(true);
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_K:
          kill(false);
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_Y:
          yank();
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_A:
          cursor.home();
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_E:
          cursor.end();
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_L:
          term.clearScreen();
          break;
        case keyAction::CTRL_W:
          deleteWord();
          break;
      }

      refresh();
    }
  }

  std::string editor::getline () {
    if (term.supported() && isatty(term.inputFileDescriptor)) {
      term.enableRawMode(term.inputFileDescriptor);

      bool output(edit(term.inputFileDescriptor, term.outputFileDescriptor));

      term.disableRawMode(term.inputFileDescriptor);

      std::cout << std::endl;

      return output?lineBuffer:"";
    } else {
      std::cout << prompt << std::flush;

      std::string retval;

      std::getline(std::cin, retval);

      return retval;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't have the time to do a completely thorough review at the moment, but here are some things that I noticed that may help you improve your code.

### Don't use `#import`

Although it is supported by some compilers, code which is intended to be reused should avoid non-standard extensions.  In this case, it's also not really needed because all of the files except for `linenoise.h` already contain an include guard, and it's a simple matter to add one to `linenoise.h`.  In a similar vein, it would probably make sense to omit the `#pragma`s as well.  They are inherently compiler-specific.  If you feel you must use them, wrap them in guards to hide them from compilers that don't support them.  (Yes, compilers will ignore `#pragma`s they don't support but this often generates a warning.)

### Don't reuse the same name for conflicting things

In the existing code, we have these lines of code:

```
  class editor {
    enum class keyAction;

    class cursor {
      friend class editor;

      const editor &editor;
```

I see a few problems with that.  First, the word `class` isn't really need in the `friend` declaration.  It's implicit because `editor` completely defines a type.  However, the more serious problem is with the last line because it changes what `editor` means.  On the line above, it referred to a class type.  Now it's a `const` reference to a class of `editor` type.  While compilers may or may not complain about this, users certainly will.  One simple way to avoid this would be to use a common convention such as using `Editor` to name the class and `editor` to signify an instance of that class.

### Eliminate unused variables

Both the parameters `stdin_fd` and `stdout_fd` are unused within the `edit()` routine. Also, the `nread` variable is set but never used.

### Initialize variables before acting on them

In the `edit` function, the variable `c` is part of the `switch` statment, but it hasn't been initialized to any particular value the first time through.

### Avoid C-style casts

If you're writing in C++, use C++ style casts rather than C-style casts.  They're safer and more explicit to the reader of your code.

### Use C-style includes

Instead of including `stdio.h` you should instead use `#include <cstdio>`.  The difference is in namespaces as you can [read about in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460250/cstdio-stdio-h-namespace).

Comment: Wrap `#pragma` in a macro or wrap them in guards? :p

Comment: In guards of course!  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: It *may* be possible to put a pragma in a macro though if `_Pragma` is used instead of `#pragma`. At least I think it is possible.

Comment: It might be possible, but it's probably not the best way to do it.

Comment: You're right. Moreover, `_Pragma` actually takes a parenthesized *string literal* which gets messy when the pragma already takes a string literal (`GCC diagnostic` for example).